# Bash (simulate a telnet client with tcp socket and obtain the first line)

Tags: bash, sockets, tcp, telnet, file-descriptor

I'm trying to simulating a telnet client in bash using **tcp socket** and I'm starting from zero.

Doing this I am reading and writing on a file descriptor (stdin stdout).

(I know that it's too much simple to do `$telnet hostname`, but I'm doing this to understand bash).

To start I want to get the first line (welcome message).

**There are some troubles with particular ip.**

With some it works, but with some others it fails. It has to go good with all!

Example with some random Ip I found to test it

**It works good with:**

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/77.239.64.182/23; cat <&3
```

output:

```
????????

*                      TELRAD CMTS UBR-10K                       *


User Access Verification

Username:
```

---

## Here the trouble

**It works bad with:**

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/77.239.64.158/23; cat <&3
```

output:

```
0???? ??#??'
```

but, if I use telnet the output it's different:

```
$ telnet 77.239.64.158
Trying 77.239.64.158...
Connected to 77.239.64.158.
Escape character is '^]'.

MikroTik v6.18
Login:
```

**I thought that the trouble was that the client had to send some string before having the welcome message**.

So I changed it to:

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/77.239.64.158/23; echo -e "aaaaaaaa\r\n\rAAAA...lonstring...AAAA\r\n\r\n\rAAAAlonstringAAAA\n\r\n" >&3; cat <&3
```

Same thing, same output.
Someone able to adjust this?!

Comment: Provide login data of a test user for testing.

Comment: @Cyrus "Provide login data of a test user for testing." It's a client not a server. Please read all the answer before commenting

Comment: You are getting some Telnet commands. You need to engage in the Telnet protocol. This is rather non-trivial. Use a Telnet client library.

Comment: @user207421 "You are getting some Telnet commands. You need to engage in the Telnet protocol. This is rather non-trivial. Use a Telnet client library." tnkz but I want to do it in pure bash to prove myself := So? What sends telnet to the server to enable the welcome message?!

Comment: You will find the necessary information [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Related_RFCs).

Comment: @Cyrus "You will find the necessary information there." I've searched there on wikipedia, but I'm not a specialist on this. If there's an expert of this Internet protocol (telnet) that can make life easier... (grateful face)

Comment: You will never do this in `bash`. There are dozens of RFCs you need to read, as per the link provided by @Cyrus, and you need to be able to process characters in binary, with some quite complex parsing required.

Comment: @user207421 "You will never do this in bash. There are dozens of RFCs you need to read, as per the link provided by Cyrus, and you need to be able to process characters in binary, with some quite complex parsing required." Do not underrate the overpower of bash. If u want all it's possible. But, if it's so much complex at least i want to grep the first line in the authentication.... if I do this then there's something like a base for me to go over. So, I can't read dozens and dozens of RFCs for knowing only how to get the first line!!!!

Comment: It is you who is underestimating this task. I have a Telnet implementation written in Java. It is several hundred lines of code. You have to do quite a lot just to get to the first line of data if there are prior Telnet commands. I don't know how many times you need to be told this.

Comment: @user207421 "It is you who is underestimating this task. I have a Telnet implementation written in Java. It is several hundred lines of code. You have to do quite a lot just to get to the first line of data if there are prior Telnet commands. I don't know how many times you need to be told this" WOW!  You're the most powerful person I know. I don't know the Java language and I don't have ever written a file with hundred line of code. So don't say me nothing anymore. I can't use telnet socket with in bash. If you say this probably it's in this way. Give up. <3 Lovviu cheers